# Continuity between Euclidean Spaces

Tags: continuity, euclidean-geometry

A function f : D ⊂ R^n → R^m is continuous at a point p ∈ D if
lim_x→p f(x) = f(p). We say that f is continuous on D if its continuous at every
point p ∈ D.

Could someone please explain this way of checking continuity between Euclidean spaces. 
I'd really appreciate if it could be demonstrated using an example.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Too broad a question I am afraid :). There are so many dimensions where you got confused. For instance, it could be the epsilon-delta definition or the intuition. So maybe you want to narrow down the scope, won't u?

Comment: Hi, to be honest, I'm just seeking a good way to tell how and when a function is uniformly continuous or just continuous. I'm referring to the epsilon-delta definition. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

The function $f(x,y)=(2x,y,x+y)$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ is continuous at $p=(0,0)$ with respcet to the euclideian metric in both spaces.

Let $\epsilon >0$.

Then $d_2(f(x,y)-f(0,0))=\sqrt{(4x^2+y^2+x^2+2xy+y^2)}=\sqrt{(5x^2+2y^2+2xy)} \leqslant \sqrt{(x^2+y^2+5x^2+2y^2)}=\sqrt{6x^2+3y^2} \leqslant \sqrt{6(x^2+y^2)}=\sqrt{6} \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{6}d_2((x,y),(0,0))$

Take $\delta= \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{6}}$ and you have that $d_2((x,y),(0,0))< \delta \Longrightarrow d_2(f(x,y),f(0,0))< \epsilon$.

Also the limit of this function at $p=(0,0)$ is $z=(0,0,0)=f(0,0)$ and this function is lipschitz continuous hence uniformly continuous.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you please explain the steps behind your working. For example, why you chose (0,0) in particular. Also, how did you get the term following the less than/equal to sign on the second line. Thank you so much again. I really appreciate it.

Comment: i took the point (0,0) as an easy example..i could chose any point because this function is continuous in all $\mathbb{R}^4$..Also $(x-y)^2 \geqslant 0$ thus $x^2+y^2 \geqslant 2xy$

Comment: You can take an arbitrary point $p=(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and you can follow the same steps and prove tat $f$ is continuous in all the space,as a practise.It will be very helpfull...I think you can handle it.:)

Comment: ***In the first comment i mean $\mathbb{R}^2$ not $\mathbb{R}^4$